# Getting elasticsearch connect error on continuous uploads

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a script that reads lines one by one from a csv file and index the same to elasticsearch in the same order. My elasticsearch host is the same machine on which the script is running. Everything else works fine except for a few rows when I suddenly start getting the following error:

```
W, [2012-10-09T14:46:00.899876 #11567]  WARN -- : Cannot assign requested address connect(2)
D, [2012-10-09T14:46:00.900037 #11567] DEBUG -- : ["/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/http/client.rb:11:in `get'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/search.rb:94:in `perform'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/search.rb:20:in `results'", "models/test.rb:31:in `get_details'", "models/test.rb:56:in `block in index_test'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1768:in `each'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1202:in `block in foreach'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1340:in `open'", "/home/azitabh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1201:in `foreach'", "models/test.rb:40:in `index_test'", "models/test.rb:85:in `<main>'"]
```

And the errors are not related to the values at those rows in the csv. I get these errors at different locations at different times.

There is another error "WAIT_TIMEOUT" which I get some time. Couldn't put the trace here as I didn't get that error this time.

I am coding in ruby and using "Tire" gem to talk to elasticsearch. I don't feel these are responsible in any way though.

JAVA was using 8% of my system's memory at the time I got this error. This is much below the assigned value ES_MIN_MEM=2g.

Thanks in advance
-Azitabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because tire doesn't close the tcp connection by itself. Once all the available ports gets engaged, no further connection is possible until system closes all connections in waiting state itself. This takes some time and any attempt to establish new connection results in wait_timeout.